# Transaction is not getting rolled back Java Android Sql

Tags: java, android, sql

*I am trying to run three asynctask one by one .
Each dependent to each other.
If any one of the task gets exception all the three task should be rolled back.
to is previous position.
But only the task which got exception is getting rolled back not others
My code is below

```
               public static int executeOrder() {
    int mOrderId=-1;
    Connection conn = null;
    JtdsCallableStatement jtdsproc = null;
    ResultSet orderResult = null;

    try {
        conn = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
        jtdsproc = (JtdsCallableStatement) conn
                .prepareCall("{call SaveOrder(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
        jtdsproc.setInt(1, SqlOrderQueries.getORDERID());
        jtdsproc.setInt(2, SqlOrderQueries.getPOSID());
        jtdsproc.setInt(3, SqlOrderQueries.getEMP_CASH_ID());
        jtdsproc.setInt(4, SqlOrderQueries.getCUST_ID());
        jtdsproc.setInt(5, SqlOrderQueries.getTRANSTYPE());
        jtdsproc.setString(6, ""+SqlOrderQueries.getMDEBIT());
        jtdsproc.setString(7, ""+SqlOrderQueries.getADEBIT());
        jtdsproc.setString(8, ""+SqlOrderQueries.getMCREDIT());
        jtdsproc.setString(9, ""+SqlOrderQueries.getACREDIT());
        jtdsproc.setString(10, ""+SqlOrderQueries.getBCREDIT());
        jtdsproc.setInt(11, SqlOrderQueries.getMEALPLANID());
        jtdsproc.setInt(12, SqlOrderQueries.getCASHRESULTID());
        jtdsproc.setInt(13, SqlOrderQueries.getLUNCHTYPE());
        jtdsproc.setInt(14, SqlOrderQueries.getSCHOOL_ID());
        jtdsproc.setString(15, SqlOrderQueries.getORDERDATE());
        jtdsproc.setInt(16, SqlOrderQueries.getCREDITAUTH());

        if(SqlOrderQueries.getCHECKNUM()== -1)
        {
            jtdsproc.setNull(17, Types.INTEGER);
        }else{
            jtdsproc.setInt(17, SqlOrderQueries.getCHECKNUM());
        }
        jtdsproc.setInt(18, SqlOrderQueries.getOVERRIDE());
        jtdsproc.setInt(19, SqlOrderQueries.getVOID());
        jtdsproc.setInt(20, SqlOrderQueries.getORDLOG_ID());
        jtdsproc.setString(21, SqlOrderQueries.getORDLOGNOTE());
        orderResult = jtdsproc.executeQuery();
        while (orderResult.next()) {

            mOrderId=orderResult.getInt(1);
            Log.w("Data For Sales Handler: OrderId",
                    "$--" + orderResult.getInt(1));
            Log.w("Data For Sales Handler OrderIdLog:",
                    "$--" + orderResult.getInt(2));
            Log.w("Data For Sales Handler Customerid:",
                    "$--" + orderResult.getInt(3));
            Log.w("Data For Sales Handler Abalance:",
                    "$--" + orderResult.getFloat(4));
            Log.w("Data For Sales Handler Mbalance:",
                    "$--" + orderResult.getFloat(5));
            Log.w("Data For Sales Handler Bonacebalance:", "$--"
                    + orderResult.getFloat(6));
            Log.w("Data For Sales Handler Error:",
                    "$--" + orderResult.getString(7));
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ee.printStackTrace();
        return mOrderId = Utilities.NETWORK_ERROR;
    }
    return mOrderId;
}
public static boolean insertItem(int mOrderid, ArrayList<Integer> itemsIds,
        ArrayList<Integer> menuItemIds, ArrayList<Integer> itemsQuantity,
        ArrayList<Integer> itemsSoldType, ArrayList<Float> itemsPrice) {
    boolean insertStatus = false;
    Connection conn = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
    String insertString = "insert into items values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertString);
        for(int i=0;i<itemsIds.size();)
        {
            pStmt.setInt(1, itemsIds.get(i));
            pStmt.setInt(2, mOrderid);
            pStmt.setInt(3, menuItemIds.get(i));
            pStmt.setInt(4, itemsQuantity.get(i));
            pStmt.setString(5, ""+itemsPrice.get(i));
            pStmt.setString(6, ""+itemsPrice.get(i));
            pStmt.setString(7, ""+1.00);
            pStmt.setInt(8, 0);
            pStmt.setInt(9, itemsSoldType.get(i));
            pStmt.setNull(10, Types.NULL);
            int a = pStmt.executeUpdate();
            Log.d("no of row affected for insert", "" + a);

            i++;
        }
        insertStatus = true;
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
                conn.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException excep) {
                excep.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        insertStatus=false;
    } finally {
        try {
            pStmt.close();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        } catch (SQLException eee) {
            eee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return insertStatus;
}
public static ArrayList<Integer> getNewItemId(int totalItems) {
    Connection conn = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
    JtdsCallableStatement jtdsproc = null;
    ArrayList<Integer> itemsIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < totalItems; i++) {
        try {
            jtdsproc = (JtdsCallableStatement) conn
                    .prepareCall("{call FASTINDEXGEN(1,1,0)}");
            ResultSet rs = jtdsproc.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Log.d("Value", "" + rs.getInt(1));
                itemsIds.add(rs.getInt(1));
            }
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
                    conn.rollback();
                } catch (SQLException excep) {
                    excep.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            itemsIds=null;
        }
    }
    return itemsIds;
}*



            public void completeOrder(InputBean input){

    setNO_PaYMENT(false);

    SqlOrderQueries.setPOSID(((HomeActivity)mActivity).mSessionManager.getPosId());
    SqlOrderQueries.setEMP_CASH_ID(((HomeActivity)mActivity).mSessionManager.getCustomerId());
    /*Customer id will be different for student and guest cash sale*/
    SqlOrderQueries.setCUST_ID(input.getCustomer_id());
    SqlOrderQueries.setTRANSTYPE(getTransType());
    SqlOrderQueries.setMDEBIT(input.getmDebit());
    SqlOrderQueries.setADEBIT(input.getaDebit());
    SqlOrderQueries.setMCREDIT(input.getmCredit());
    SqlOrderQueries.setACREDIT(input.getaCredit());
    SqlOrderQueries.setBCREDIT(""+0.00);

    /*Do not need to change the meal plan id ,it is default by default*/
    SqlOrderQueries.setCASHRESULTID(((HomeActivity)mActivity).mSessionManager.getCashColumnId());

    SqlOrderQueries.setLUNCHTYPE(DetailsFragment.getLUNCH_TYPE());
    SqlOrderQueries.setSCHOOL_ID(((HomeActivity)mActivity).mSessionManager.getSchoolId());
    SqlOrderQueries.setORDERDATE(getDate());
    /*Credit auth is passed default for the time being*/
    SqlOrderQueries.setCHECKNUM(input.getCheckNumber());
    /*override is passed 0 for the time being*/
    /*void ordlog_id  ordlognote  are  0 ,default ,default respectfully*/


    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>() {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if(ConnectionProvider.checkConnection()==false){

                return null;
            }
            return OrderSalesHandler.executeOrder();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result == Utilities.NETWORK_ERROR)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder mEAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
                mEAlert.setMessage("Network Problem");
                mEAlert.create().show();
            }
            if(result>0){

                mItemshandler.onSucessOrder(result);
            }

        }


    }.execute();
}

@Override
public void onSucessOrder(int orderId) {

    mOrderid=orderId;
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Integer>>(){

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Integer> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if(ConnectionProvider.checkConnection()==false){
                return null;
            }
            return OrderSalesHandler.getNewItemId(mTotalItems);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Integer> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result==null)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder mEAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
                mEAlert.setMessage("Network Problem and Order not Completed");
                mEAlert.create().show();
            }else{

                mItemshandler.onSucessItemId(result);
            }

        }


    }.execute();
}

@Override
public void onSucessItemId(ArrayList<Integer> itemIds) {



    itemsIds=itemIds;
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(){

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

            if(ConnectionProvider.checkConnection()==false)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return OrderSalesHandler.insertItem(mOrderid,itemsIds,menuItemIds,itemsQuantity,itemsSoldType,itemsPrice);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result==true){

                if(isNO_PaYMENT()==false){

                    ((HomeActivity)mActivity).mSalesFragment.mPaymentDialog.dismiss();
                }

                ((HomeActivity)mActivity).mSalesFragment.onClick(((HomeActivity)mActivity).mSalesFragment.mCancelButton);


            }

            if(result==false){

                AlertDialog.Builder mEAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
                mEAlert.setMessage("Network Problem and Order Not Completed");
                mEAlert.create().show();
            }
        }



    }.execute();
}



public static boolean isNO_PaYMENT() {
    return NO_PaYMENT;
}

public static void setNO_PaYMENT(boolean nO_PaYMENT) {
    NO_PaYMENT = nO_PaYMENT;
}
```

}

interface InsertItemshandler {

```
public void onSucessOrder(int result);
public void onSucessItemId(ArrayList<Integer> itemsIds);
```

}

Comment: *"If any one of the task gets exception all the three task should be rolled back"* - I suppose you should really wrap the three separate database transactions into one in order to achieve that.

Comment: thanks for the reply well did i need to put all code in single try catch or multiple ?

Comment: Hi passing the Connection reference will work or not ?

Comment: In theory that could work, provided you don't commit until the final database work (from the 3rd task) has finished. I would, however, refactor the code so that you end up with a much more manageable, single `AsyncTask` that interacts with the database. Do you have a specific reason for spreading the logic out over multiple tasks (as it current stands)?

Comment: Hi i got it correct by passing the connection reference from  each method to other . That is working fine. And as you said i set  autocommit false in connection .

Comment: well i do not have any specific reasons for creating separate tasks. But just want to confirm if i do by  passing the connection reference for  executing my async task ,is it a good practice or i keep a Singleton reference of my connection or as you said or i use intentservice which is better